# Displaying date and time based on other conditions

Tags: tables, grid, minimalist

I have 5 columns (Order #, Product, Status, Priority, and Date).

The values in the Date Column are displayed based on the `Status` column. For example, if the status is `Request`, then show the requested date time, and all other explanations are also attached in the screenshot (refer to the Date field explanation).

The way I designed I feel the information is too crisp and there is a need to explain that the request was raised 20 mins ago, 2 days late passed the scheduled date, a day left to the actual scheduled date, etc...

Is there a better way to design and achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer. The "Priority" confuses me.  What does it mean for a closed item to have high priority?  If the priority is assigned at the beginning and never changes, the column would be better understood if it were moved further left. But if the priority actually *is* associated with the status, then what does it mean for a closed item to have high priority?

Comment: Maybe the column's arrangement is confusing. But the `Priority` is assigned at the beginning and didn't change. Order #6 is closed now which had the `High` priority. 

The Priority should be moved further left? Does that mean the priority should in between Product and Status?

Comment: It's somewhat subjective, but I tend to order columns in order of permanence. The Order# will *never* change. The Product might occasionally change, but only right at the beginning. Its Priority will almost never change. Its Status *will* change several times. And the Date will change every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might make a few meager suggestions:

1. Aggregate the Status and "Date" columns - first of all, the "date" column is not really a date, it is an expansion of the status explaining the time factor relative to that status. Rather than two columns (broken up by a third, no less), have a single Status column that tells the user all of that information in an easy-to-read way. The table could be sortable by Priority or Order number (or perhaps Status, depending on how you do it), and color could be reserved for important statuses or priority

[image]

2. Perhaps break up the table into sections by some factor. For example below I'm showing tabs for the actual "stage" of the process - as separated out from the "Status", which might allow for easier parsing of the data - within there sorting could help to further refine the records:

[image]

There could be ways to alert users to important attention needed on a specific tab (icons, color, etc), or you might not use tabs at all, but expandable sections for each stage in the process, or each priority ranking.

3. You might leave it as a single table and provide controls to make it sortable and filterable, allowing users to focus the table on the data they want to see - for example, allow them to simply filter by High priority items, regardless of status:

[image]

Or "late" items, regardless of Priority:

[image]

That latter is probably the most flexible and usable based on my limited understanding of your needs.

Anyway, these are just a few very broad options that will need tweaking for your scenario. Take them as you will, since you know your context better than we do!

Best of luck.

Comment: May I ask what app did you use to design the mockups?

Comment: A scratch page in Figma, with some components we've built for my company

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the use of colors to convey information. While it's possible to use them, it's not foolproof from an accessibility standpoint, AND they are used to convey information on two different sets that may or may not align, as seen in the **"Scheduled" / "Two days late"** row.

This is not a simple task and obviously requires testing, but I would start by cleaning up things. For example, is the time information for **"closed," "completed,"** or **"on hold"** really important? I'm not saying it isn't, but I'm offering something for you to consider.

From my perspective, those variables indicate that there's nothing more to be done with them, rendering the time data somewhat useless for technicians. However, it might be useful for a project manager. So, **it depends on your use case.**

Now, let's return to priorities and colors.

The priorities are set at the beginning of the task (e.g., when a client requests it). They carry weight for the future, and their status is relatively static. However, once a task is overdue or nearing its deadline, **the status should become dynamic**. Even if it was initially assigned a low priority, it should change if it's two days overdue. In that case, it should clearly be marked as the highest priority or be rescheduled. Otherwise, conflicting information arises, such as **something being scheduled, labeled as low or medium priority, and being two days in the past.**

**With this in mind, I would suggest the following:**

- Make the variables dynamic.
- Allow for rescheduling.
- Add another variable for "behind schedule" or "late."

**Now, regarding the colors:**

- Make all projects that don't require immediate attention gray. You can even add shades of gray, gradually transitioning to pure black (e.g., for "closed").
- Use only one color code. If something is late, everything related to that item should be marked as late, and therefore displayed in red. This principle should apply to all aspects.
- Avoid using additional colors for the priority. At some point, conflicts will arise. The priority itself should provide enough information.

**As for the table:**

- Increase the padding in the cells.
- Dim the lines slightly to maintain visibility without causing visual noise. Alternatively, you could convert each row into a dismissible card.